# Get Row Info from sql server database using image

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

This is my first question, I hope I find the best way to express my need

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and ADO.NET Entity Framework in a Windows forms application.

I have a table in my database called `ParentMedia` that has columns `ID, TITLE, URL, Image`.

I dynamically created a picturebox at runtime for every row in the database and each picturebox has the image from table `ParentMedia`

What I need to do is a way to :

When I click on the image in the picturebox I can read the info corresponding to this image in database table like `ID` and `Title`

Each image in database has unique `ID` and unique `Title`

Comment: Just take into account that an image is just an array of bytes (byte[]). Try to write some code and come back to us with more questions about.